# How to get an admin token from REST API when 2FA is enabled and using U2F?

Tags: rest-api, webapi, 2fa

Magento 2.4.2-p2

Greetings,

I'm interested in to get an admin token from the REST API when 2FA is enabled and as authentication provider U2F is used.
I have a small application running on another server that modifies some Product attributes from time to time. This application needs the admin token for authentication.

I have configured 2FA successfully and can login via U2F (YubiKey) to the adminhtml.
However, I cannot find any documentation on how to authenticate through the REST API using U2F.

Here is a documentation on how this would work with Google Authenticator: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/prerequisite-tasks/create-admin-token.html

I have found some endpoints in the REST API docs that seem to correspond to the u2fkey authorization (search for u2fkey). Especially, the https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.3-admin/tag/tfaprovideru2fkeyauthentication-challenge seems to be a starting point, but I cannot figure out, how to deal with the response.

I am grateful for any help or push that will lead me in the right direction.

Another concern of mine is that I probably have to provide the OTP every time the admin token exceeded. Am I right? I really don't want to increase the lifetime of admin tokens (default is 4 hours) for security reasons. Maybe this restriction requires a completely different solution then using 2FA over REST API.

Thanks, Densen

Comment: https://docs.celigo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056464011-Authorize-your-Integration-App-connection-to-support-Magento-two-factor-authentication

Comment: Do you found a solution? It's urgent for me.

Answer (score 1):

you're right, if you want to generate a session-based access token, you will need to provide the 2FA code.

Your request will seems like this one below.

[image: Magento authentication 2FA REST API]

Although, based on your context, I recommend you to use the integration token, that you won't have expiration date, since you have a programmatically connection.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html#integration-tokens